# Is it possible to get a blackboard-bold 0?

Tags: fonts, blackboard

I've found that `\mathbb{1}` works when using `mathpazo`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
    $\mathbb{1}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

But `\mathbb{0}` doesn't work (doesn't display anything at all), and my searches haven't led me to any solutions so far. Is it possible to get a blackboard-bold 0? Or other numbers?

Comment: Have you tied `\mathbb{0}`? You will need to tell us which packages you are using, and give a MWE.

Comment: I was using `mathpazo`. And no, `\mathbb{0}` doesn't work.

Comment: Please consider about cmathbb.sty

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the `bbold` font has the blackboard bold "0", although it is not shown in the "comprehensive symbols index" (`texdoc comprehensive` from your command line if you have tex live installed), table 213, "math alphabets".  the other blackboard bold fonts shown there do *not* have the zero, although some of them have other digits.

Answer (score 14):

you can try to run `xelatex` or `lualatex` with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
    $\mathbb{0}\mathbb{1}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

or with `Asana Math` instead of the STIX fonts:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`Cmathbb.sty` also a solution for this, and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmathbb}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{123456789}$

$\mathbb{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$

$\mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, if you don't want to use any `font package`, then you can try with `contour.sty` and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[auto]{contour}
\begin{document}

\contour{black}{\color{white}123456789}

\contour{black}{\color{white}abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}

\contour{black}{\color{white}ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer seems to be a bit short. You could add a MWE and show the result.

Comment: I'm not in system,so only I suggest the package name only, I will post the code once I'll be in system

Comment: Also if any error in my suggestion or if my suggestion doesn't meet op requirement then you can downvote else should not do

Comment: I found your answer in the review queue of low quality posts, and it already had -1 when I wrote my comment. I voted "Looks OK" with the expectation that you may add to the answer later.

Comment: It should be noted that as of now, the `cmathbb` fonts wont work on case-sensitive systems such as Linux due to a bug.

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis Yes, I agree with you.

Comment: Notably absent from this response is the '0' specifically requested...