# \mathbb{0} and \mathbb{1} with mathdesign/Utopia?

Tags: fonts, blackboard

In a [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44283/is-it-possible-to-get-a-blackboard-bold-0), I asked about getting a blackboard bold 0 in addition to a 1. But now I'd like to do it along with `\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}`. If I try to `\usepackage{bbold}`, I get the error

```
Latex Error: /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bbold/bbold.sty:42 LaTeX Error: Command `\mathbb' already defined.
```

It seems that `\usepackage{dsmath}` works with `\mathds{01}`, but if possible I'd like to use them with the command `\mathbb`. Is there a way to make that work?

Comment: Just say `\let\mathbb\relax` before `\usepackage{bbold}`, which should go after the call to `mathdesign`. However consider that this font is rather visually incompatible with Utopia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\let\mathbb\undefined  % delete the command definition 
\usepackage{bbold}     % let bbold define its own \mathbb command

\begin{document}

$\mathbb{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}$

\end{document}
```

This example works, but I haven't done any further tests.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to Micheal Palmer's answer, I did the following: declare a new math alphabet and use that (learned that trick from another answer at TeX.SX, don't have a reference at hand).

```
% Copied and modified from bbold.sty:
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbbold}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}

$\mathbbold{1}$
```