# type of zero in article

Tags: math-mode, fonts

How can I write a **zero[image]**? I want this zero that have **two bar** inside its. Can I help me?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44283/is-it-possible-to-get-a-blackboard-bold-0

Answer (score 1):

The zero of your screenshot.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[bb=boondox]{mathalfa}

\begin{document}
$\mathbb{0}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for answering. these codes work in article document but dont work for beamer doucument. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @ToubaParsa You use `\documentclass{beamer}`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to overriding `\mathbb` with the boondox font that would also change the shape of blackboard bold capitals, might be using the STIX fonts (importing only the required glyph).

From the documentation of `stix2` we see that blackboard bold is in `stix-mathbb`. We can go backwards and look for `\mathbb` in `stix2.sty` to see

```
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}  {symbols3}
```

Then, looking for `symbols3`,

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols3}      {LS1}{stix2bb}   {m} {n}
```

Good, we can even avoid defining new font encodings by looking in `ls1stix2bb.fd` and the relevant lines are

```
\DeclareFontFamily{LS1}{stix2bb}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{LS1}{stix2bb}{m}{n} {<-> stix2-mathbb}{}
```

Here's the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{stix2bb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{stix2bb}{m}{n} {<-> stix2-mathbb}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\stixbbdigit}{m}{%
  \text{\usefont{U}{stix2bb}{m}{n}#1}%
}
\newcommand{\bbzero}{\stixbbdigit{0}}
\newcommand{\bbone}{\stixbbdigit{1}}

\begin{document}

$A+\bbzero\ne\bbone$

\end{document}
```

[image]